# ggplot aes fill uses only one color

Tags: python, python-ggplot

I recently had to reformat my system at work and after reinstalling anaconda and ggplot I am observing some funny behavior for graphs.

The anaconda environment has the default packages and ggplot version is 0.9.4-py35_0 from conda-forge.

The dataset I used for this example was from the [kaggle shelter animal outcomes](https://www.kaggle.com/c/shelter-animal-outcomes/data)

If i run the following code I should get a segmented bar graph with colors according to the 'OutcomeType' Value in the legend.

`ggplot(train, aes(x='AnimalType', fill='OutcomeType')) + geom_bar(position='fill')`

However, while I expect something like this:

[image]

I end up with this instead:

[image]

For some reason it appears that the 'fill' argument for aes is not functioning properly. While the legend entries for the fill values have differently colored labels, those colors are not displayed on the different segments of the bar graph. Any ideas as to why this is the case?

Thanks in advance for any help!